# Why isn't my javascript onclick event triggered on the first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element that I click and it is supposed to trigger a check of the current innerHTML value of the element and then match to a condition and make changes.

Is it the position of the script relative to the position of the element or is it about loading? The script is above the element but it works on the second and subsequent clicks(alternating not shown).

The innerHTML won't change on first click but another event like hiding something works on first click.

**HTML**

```
<div id="element" onclick="changeHim();">Change me upon click.</div>
```

**Script**

```
function changeHim() {
var currentLabel = document.getElementById("element");
if(currentLabel=="Change me upon click"){
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML="You have been changed.";
}
```

}

Comment: Well you're missing the closing bracket of your function, but perhaps you just didn't post that. (Better indentation helps avoid errors of this nature.)

Comment: Wow! in 5 minutes you have 5 answers.. kudos to stackoverflow

Comment: I know, stackoverflow is a great community / resource a wealth of information, just spewing, imagine the servers.

Comment: @janicehoplin yes.. verity..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error No 1.

you should declare

```
var currentLabel = document.getElementById("element").innerHTML
```

instead of

```
var currentLabel = document.getElementById("element");
```

Error No 2.

Function closing Bracket } is missing

Error No 3.

Use

```
if(currentLabel=="Change me upon click."){
```

Instead of

```
if(currentLabel=="Change me upon click"){
```

because one DOT(.) is missing in the (innterHTML) text

the corrected FULL code (tested) is given below

```
<script>
  function changeHim() {
    var currentLabel = document.getElementById("element").innerHTML;
    if(currentLabel=="Change me upon click."){
      document.getElementById("element").innerHTML="You have been changed.";
      }
    }
</script>

<div id="element" onclick="changeHim();">Change me upon click.</div>
```

Comment: Check my answer and give +1 if you feel it is correct,

Comment: thanks, I appreciate everyone elses' help, I usually don't choose an answer but I understand

Answer (score 2):

The result of `getElementById` is a DOM element instead of the content of that div.
So the statement

```
if (currentLabel == "change me upon click")
```

is never `true`.

Comment: I don't understand that, how would it work at all? Or maybe it is triggering the else condition which doesn't match anything. (not shown above).

Comment: Oh man, I see it, I alerted currentLabel.innerHTML and it shows <span class...text.../>

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with innerHTML:

```
if(currentLabel.innerHTML=="Change me upon click"){
```

Also, fix the missing closing brace `}` of your function.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the text label as:

```
var currentLabel = document.getElementById("element").textContent;
```

or

```
var currentLabel = document.getElementById("element").innerHtml;
```

Comment: Close the thread by accepting an answer and helping others who might face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

your `if` statement is causing the problem it should be `if (currentLabel.innerHTML == "Change me upon click.")`

```js
function changeHim() {
    var currentLabel = document.getElementById("element");
    if (currentLabel.innerHTML == "Change me upon click.") {
        document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = "You have been changed.";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="element" onclick="changeHim();">Change me upon click.</div>
```